How to seperate sequelize models into different files?
I am using Sequelize with TypeScript in Node.js. My question is how to spread sequelize models into different files and import them afterwards into one. Maybe an example:
database.ts
import { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model, Op } from 'sequelize'
import constants from "../../utils/constants"

//create connection
const sequelize = new Sequelize(constants.DATABASE, constants.USERNAME, constants.PASSWORD, {
    host: constants.HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        connectTimeout: 10000
    },
    port: constants.DBPORT,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
    }
});

sequelize.authenticate().catch(err => {
    console.error("err: ", err)
});

export { sequelize }

userModel.ts
import { sequelize } from "./model"
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize'

interface UserAttributes {
    ID: number,
    EMail: string;
    Password: string;
    Balance: number;
}

interface UserInstance extends Model<UserAttributes>, UserAttributes {}

const User = sequelize.define<UserInstance>("User", {
    ID: {   
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        unique: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    EMail: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    Password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    Balance: {
        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    },
    
    {
        timestamps: false,
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    },

);

export {
    User,
    UserInstance
}

what if i have models referencing to that model? like
import { sequelize } from "./model"
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize'
import { User } from "./userModel"
import { Stock } from "./stockModel"

interface TransactionAttributes {
    TID: number
    PriceAtAquisition: number
    TransactionQuantity: number
    Date: Date
    UID: number
    SISIN: string
}

interface TransactionInstance extends Model<TransactionAttributes>, TransactionAttributes {}

const Transaction = sequelize.define<TransactionInstance>("Transaction", {
    TID: {   
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    PriceAtAquisition: {
        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    TransactionQuantity: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    Date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    UID:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: User,
            key: 'ID'
          }
    },
    SISIN: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Stock,
            key: 'ISIN'
          }
    },
    },

    {
        timestamps: false,
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    },

);

export {
    Transaction,
    TransactionInstance
}

i get the error this if i try to run with nodemon:
const User = sequelize.define<UserInstance>("User", {
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'define')

I looked up on the internet but found nothing useful for my case
